# Por que há divergência de resultado a depender de como a expressão regular é executada no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Qual o motivo da divergência de resultado encontrada ao executar uma mesma expressão regular de formas diferentes no JavaScript?

Expressão regular:

```
^([a-z][a-z0-9]{0,30}\.)?((?!\d+\.)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,24}[a-z0-9])?)(\.[a-z]{2,4}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$
```

Método 1 (funciona adequadamente):

```
function valida_dominio(value){
    return /^([a-z][a-z0-9]{0,30}\.)?((?!\d+\.)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,24}[a-z0-9])?)(\.[a-z]{2,4}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/.test(value);
}
```

Método 2 (não funciona adequadamente):

```
function valida_dominio(value){
      let str_pattern = '^([a-z][a-z0-9]{0,30}\.)?((?!\d+\.)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,24}[a-z0-9])?)(\.[a-z]{2,4}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$';
      let pattern = new RegExp(str_pattern, "i");
      return pattern.test(value);
}
```

O objetivo do método 2 é poder passar expressão regular como uma string. Porém não funciona adequadamente. Por exemplo:

- aprova o domínio "cëa.br" que é inválido;
- aprova o domínio "26caracteres-asdfasdfasdfa.com.br" que é válido.

Como fazer para que o método 2 funcione adequadamente? Ou seja, como passar a expressão regular via string sem que apresente divergência no resultado?

OBS: No [RegExp](https://regexr.com/4sd0n) e no método 1 a expressão regular funciona corretamente.

Comment: Outra diferença, além da questão da ``\``, é a flag `i` no método 2. Por padrão, `[a-z]` só considera letras minúsculas, mas com a flag `i` a regex também vai pegar letras maiúsculas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quando você utiliza a barra invertida `\` dentro de uma string, você está escapando o próximo caractere.

Ou seja, quando você escreve `"\."` na string literal, seu interpretador irá entender como se você estivesse tentando escapar `.`, quando na verdade você queria expressar o valor literal `\.`.

Então para escrever uma expressão regular equivalente como string, você precisaria escapar a própria barra invertida, ou seja:

`"^([a-z][a-z0-9]{0,30}\\.)?((?!\\d+\\.)[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,24}[a-z0-9])?)(\\.[a-z]{2,4}(?:\\.[a-z]{2})?)$"`

Comment: É isso mesmo. Outra coisa que pode até não afetar no comportamento atual mas é importante ressaltar caso tenha passado despercebida, é a ausência da flag `i` no método 1 e a sua presença no 2. Apenas para evitar futuros problemas.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente! É algo básico, mas tinha esquecido totalmente de pensar nas barras invertidas! Muito obrigado!